# Syntax error in my first script.(min, max)

Tags: awk, syntax-error, max, min

I want to find the minimum and the maximum value of my data.
My data file:

```
1
2
4
5
-3
-13
112
-3
55
42
42
```

And my script:

```
{min=max=$1}    
{if ($1<min) {min=$1} else {next} }   
{if ($1>max) {max=$1} else {next} }    
END { print min , max }
```

It does nothing when I run it. 
Could you help me?

Comment: you should put your input example in code block, so that no format was lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i<min) {min=$i};if ($i>max) {max=$i}}} END {print "min="min,"max="max}' file
min=-13 max=112
```

You need to test every element, one by one. To do this we use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is, you should do `{min=max=$1}` only on the first row. also, the `next` was used wrongly. you just compared `min`, then next, so the `max` part could be skipped by mistake.

try this:

```
awk 'NR==1{min=max=$1}
    {min=$0<min?$0:min;max=$0>max?$0:max}
    END{printf "min:%s\nmax:%s\n",min,max}' file
```

it outputs:

```
min:-13
max:112
```